# Pass drawable image in an ImageView variable

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable

how to convert an image from drawable file to an Image view
because this won't work

```
ImageView image= R.drawable.pic;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pic));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

**or**

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic,this.getTheme()));
     }else {
         fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic));
```